# A generalization of Barrow's inequality

Tags: geometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

I proposed the conjecture as following:

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, $P$ be arbitrary point inside of $ABC$, let $A_1B_1C_1$ be the tangential of ABC. Let A', B', C' be three be arbitrary points on $B_1C_1, C_1A_1, A_1B_1$ respectively. Let internal angle bisectors of three angles $\angle B'PC'$, $\angle C'PA'$, $\angle A'PC'$ meet $BC, CA, AB$  at $A'', B'', C''$ respectively. Then show that:
$$PA'+PB'+PC' \ge 2(PA''+PB''+PC'')$$. 
Equality hold iff ABC be an equilateral triangle and  $\angle B'PC'= \angle C'PA'=\angle A'PC' =120^0$ 
When $A'=A, B'=B, C'=C$ we have [Barrow's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrow%27s_inequality)

Can you check in [The Meterial Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/KY8NPgGB)
[image]